# How do I extend the PriorityQueue Class

Tags: java

I need to develop a class for a Library which utilises the PriorityQueue feature in Java. I can use the PriorityQueue directly as an entity, but I want to encapsulate it in a specific class.

The trouble I am having is that I don't seem to be able to 'extend' the PriorityQueue class.

e.g.

```
public class myPriorityQueue extends PriorityQueue {

 ...

}
```

When I try and use the new class, NetBeans 8 just bombs with all sorts of errors. Further if I wade my way through - it doesn't allow the @Override of the supposedly inherited 'add' method.

I am a newbie - but any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share details about the "all sorts of errors"?

Comment: What kind of errors? Did you set your java classpath in your environment variables? Did you import `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: Extending `PriorityQueue` and overriding the `add` method works very well for me. Please provide more details what exactly does not work.

Comment: Why? What's the purpose? Surely all you need to do is provide a class argument and possibly a `Comparator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is a generic class, thus your inherited class must also be generic, try this:

```
public class myPriorityQueue<E> extends PriorityQueue<E> {
...
}
```

In short it must state during instantiation which types of objects it will be able to hold. To read more on generics I recommend you search here on SO and read a few of the many tutorials available.